# Performance of regression tree rpart

Tags: r, cart, cross-validation, rpart

I am running a regression tree using rpart and I would like to understand how well it is performing.

I know that rpart has cross validation built in, so I should not divide the dataset before of the training.

Now, I build my tree and finally I ask to see the cp.

```
> fit <- rpart(slope ~ ., data = ph1)
> printcp(fit)

Regression tree:
rpart(formula = slope ~ ., data = ph1)

Variables actually used in tree construction:
[1] blocksize dimension maps      reducers 

Root node error: 8.9483/364 = 0.024583

n= 364 

        CP nsplit rel error  xerror     xstd
1 0.517156      0   1.00000 1.00305 0.095998
2 0.155374      1   0.48284 0.48686 0.047503
3 0.116019      2   0.32747 0.37237 0.034623
4 0.029928      3   0.21145 0.22534 0.021952
5 0.018020      4   0.18152 0.21134 0.021075
6 0.016643      5   0.16350 0.20052 0.021303
7 0.015986      7   0.13022 0.18776 0.021119
8 0.010000      8   0.11423 0.15334 0.016906
```

Now I don't follow anymore.

What are those number?

If it was a **classification** I could follow those number thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666212/how-to-compute-error-rate-from-a-decision-tree)

But what about a **regression** tree ?

The test sample is [here](https://gist.github.com/siscia/313e724d60e236236a16797a30a9197e)

Comment: What data are `ph1`? Please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with.

Comment: @lmo, no, there are just 8...

Answer (score 5):

**CP table is the most important part of the RPART, it gives the complexity of the tree model (cp column) training error (rel error) and cross validation error (xerror).**

I have a set of notes on how every numbers are calculated. But I am running a regression on the mtcar data set. Note directly to your question but I think it can answer your question well. Sorry the annotation might be little messy.

[image]

[image]

I would suggest you to read [RPART manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/vignettes/longintro.pdf) Page 20. And if possible the original [cart book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0412048418).

Comment: your answer is excellent +1.  I like your links particularly the ,classic book by Breiman, Friedman, Olshen and Stone..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sperrorest` package to estimate the performance of your model. Various error measures are returned.

The following code is taken from `?sperrorest`. You are welcome to modify `pred.fun` to your needs. This is just an example.

The actual code syntax refers to version 1.0.0 which is currently available from Github using `devtools::install_github("pat-s/sperrorest")`.

```
data(ecuador) # Muenchow et al. (2012), see ?ecuador
fo <- slides ~ dem + slope + hcurv + vcurv + log.carea + cslope

# Example of a classification tree fitted to this data:
library(rpart)
ctrl <- rpart.control(cp = 0.005) # show the effects of overfitting
fit <- rpart(fo, data = ecuador, control = ctrl)
par(xpd = TRUE)
plot(fit, compress = TRUE, main = 'Stoyans landslide data set')
text(fit, use.n = TRUE)

# Non-spatial 5-repeated 10-fold cross-validation:
mypred.rpart <- function(object, newdata) predict(object, newdata)[, 2]
nspres <- sperrorest(data = ecuador, formula = fo,
                     model.fun = rpart, model.args = list(control = ctrl),
                     pred.fun = mypred.rpart,
                     smp.fun = partition.cv, 
                     smp.args = list(repetition = 1:5, nfold = 10))
summary(nspres$error.rep)                    
summary(nspres$error.fold)

                      mean          sd       median         IQR
train.auroc       7.465106e-01 0.005186850 7.478738e-01 0.003922117
train.error       2.953111e-01 0.005235886 2.952222e-01 0.004166667
train.accuracy    7.046889e-01 0.005235886 7.047778e-01 0.004166667
train.sensitivity 6.742444e-01 0.011529458 6.727778e-01 0.016000000
train.specificity 7.351333e-01 0.005994030 7.361111e-01 0.007111111
train.fpr70       3.115111e-01 0.017166685 3.202222e-01 0.023777778
train.fpr80       4.801778e-01 0.022528528 4.900000e-01 0.035222222
train.fpr90       6.819556e-01 0.015305853 6.808889e-01 0.019555556
train.tpr80       5.599111e-01 0.016436447 5.530000e-01 0.023000000
train.tpr90       3.345556e-01 0.013286259 3.297778e-01 0.022444444
train.tpr95       1.702667e-01 0.017200632 1.728889e-01 0.004666667
train.events      9.000000e+03 0.000000000 9.000000e+03 0.000000000
train.count       1.800000e+04 0.000000000 1.800000e+04 0.000000000
test.auroc        6.446438e-01 0.008173371 6.446755e-01 0.003872000
test.error        3.863000e-01 0.004590752 3.850000e-01 0.006500000
test.accuracy     6.137000e-01 0.004590752 6.150000e-01 0.006500000
test.sensitivity  5.890000e-01 0.018179659 5.960000e-01 0.021000000
test.specificity  6.384000e-01 0.012601587 6.350000e-01 0.020000000
test.fpr70        5.156000e-01 0.020634922 5.190000e-01 0.034000000
test.fpr80        6.286000e-01 0.018447222 6.360000e-01 0.017000000
test.fpr90        7.910000e-01 0.018547237 7.880000e-01 0.008000000
test.tpr80        3.978000e-01 0.009364828 3.970000e-01 0.004000000
test.tpr90        1.844000e-01 0.012239281 1.870000e-01 0.014000000
test.tpr95        8.560000e-02 0.020767763 8.800000e-02 0.025000000
test.events       1.000000e+03 0.000000000 1.000000e+03 0.000000000
test.count        2.000000e+03 0.000000000 2.000000e+03 0.000000000
```

Answer (score -1):

All the details for the CP calculation with numerical examples are show here https://sites.google.com/stern.nyu.edu/rdeo/home

Comment: Welcome to the site. At present this is more of a comment than an answer. You could 
expand it, perhaps by giving a summary of the information at the link, or we can 
convert it into a comment for you.

Comment: Welcome to CV.  Because duplicate answers do not fit within this site's aims, I have deleted your other two identical posts.  Please see our [help] for more information and guidance.